# Por que se me angostan los componentes en Angular Material

Tags: angular

Tengo el siguiente codigo en mi archivo .html de mi componente venta:

```
<div>
<mat-card class="mat-elevation-z0">
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <mat-card-title>Nueva Venta</mat-card-title>
    </div>
    <mat-card-content>
      <mat-label class="title"> Fecha/Hora:        {{ jstoday }}</mat-label>
      <br>
      <form [formGroup]="ventaForm">
        <div class="container" fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row" fxLayoutGap="20px" >
          <ng-template matStepLabel>Condicion de Venta</ng-template>
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill" fxFlex="25">
          <mat-label>Condicion.:</mat-label>
          <mat-select #condVenta placeholder="Condicion de Venta"  formControlName="condicionVenta" (selectionChange)="selectCV($event.value)" cdkFocusInitial>
            <mat-option value=undefined>Seleccione</mat-option>
            <mat-option value=1>Contado</mat-option>
            <mat-option value=2>Cuenta Corriente</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
            <span class="fill-space"></span>
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="example-full-width" fxFlex="75" >
          <mat-label>Cliente</mat-label>
          <input matInput #icliente
                 aria-label="Cliente"
                 [matAutocomplete]="auto"
                 [formControl]="clienteCtrl"
                 formControlName="nombre_cliente">
          <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete"  >
                <ng-container *ngFor="let c of filteredClientes | async" >
                <mat-option id="c.idcliente" *ngIf="c.nombre_cliente=='CONSUMIDOR FINAL'" [value]="c.nombre_cliente" (onSelectionChange)="selectC(c)">

                  <span>{{c.nombre_cliente}}</span> 
                
                </mat-option>
                <mat-option *ngIf="c.nombre_cliente!=='CONSUMIDOR FINAL'" [value]="c.nombre_cliente + '  CUIT: '+  c.CUIT" (onSelectionChange)="selectC(c)">

                  <span>{{c.nombre_cliente}}</span> |
                  <small>CUIT.: {{c.CUIT}}</small>

                </mat-option>
              </ng-container>
              </mat-autocomplete>
            </mat-form-field>
          <br>
     
            
          <table mat-table tabindex="4" #table [dataSource]="carritoDataSource$" class="mat-el" class="mat-elevation-z1" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8" matSortActive="nombreProducto" matSortDirection="asc" matSortDisableClear>
              
                  <caption style="font-size: 20px;height: 4vh;border: 10px; color: rgb(54, 11, 211);"> DETALLE </caption>
              
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="nombreProducto">
              
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Descripcion</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.NombreProducto}}</td>
              
                  </ng-container>
              
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="precio">
              
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Precio</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.precio | currency:'$'}}</td>
              
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="categoria">
              
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Categoria</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.nombre_categoria}}</td>
              
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="subcategoria">
              
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Subcategoria</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.nombre_subcategoria}}</td>
              
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="marca">
              
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Marca</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.nombre_marca}}</td>
              
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="stock">
              
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Stock</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.stock}}</td>
              
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
              
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Acciones</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              
                      <button mat-raised-button color="basic">Editar</button> |
                      <!-- <button (click)="delete(element)" mat-raised-button color="warn">Eliminar</button>-->
                    </td>
              
              
                  </ng-container>
                  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnas"></tr>
                  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:columnas"></tr>
              
                </table>
                <mat-paginator #productsPaginator [pageSizeOptions]="[50, 100,200]" showFirstLastButtons aria-label="Seleccionar pagina">
                </mat-paginator>
          
            </div>
          </form>
     
      </mat-card-content>
 </mat-card>

</div>
```

Pero no entiendo porque aparece como en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que el selectde condicion de venta ocupe un 25 % de la linea o fila y el resto del espacio(75%) lo ocupe el input de nombre de Cliente por ejemplo.

Comment: Deberias darle width: 100% a la etiqueta mat-card-content.

Comment: ejecute un simil de tu codigo y si el  <div class="container".....> contiene a la tabla no se muestra Cliente con un 75 %.Si container se cierra fuera de la tabla  muestra a Condicion 25% y cliente 75% y a la tabla en otra fila no copiaste tu css por lo cual no lo pude implementar en forma identica pero lo anterior es lo que ocurre lo cual me parece logico ya que es lo que se pide

Comment: es que hay una tabla dentro de un form esta no acepta incluirse dentro de un <mat-form-field> si se intenta hacerlo lanzo error mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl asi que me parece que una solucion es lo que comente sobre container

Comment: subi el borrador a https://github.com/nestdanchia/NgZone/tree/main/src/app/card esta en ruta card

Comment: Probe con tu codigo y probe sacar la tabla y sigue igual, tambien probe darle un width:100% al mat-card-content y sigue igual..CSS no tengo nada

Comment: como no te puedo enviar foto en este comentario lo publico como respuesta porque me muestra lo que entiendo decis que queres lograr cualquier cosa aguardo tu comentario

Comment: modifique la respuesta para mostrar como poder si  agregar elementos al conteiner al considerar el tamaño de fxLayoutGap para que los elementos se alinien de acuerdo a como querramos con calc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay un problema con la directiva fxLayoutGap que es la que define el espacio entre los items flexibles dentro del container ya que agrega  margin-right or margin-bottom  y pude entrar en conflicto con **Default value  nowrap**
Para poder controlar que los items flexibles permanezcan en una misma linea o fluyan en varias debemos usar warp y calc si es que no! queremos forzar con una configuracion css que produzca efectos inesperados al no tener en cuenta adecuadamente el efecto de  fxLayoutGap
Para esto:
Hay que calcular el tamaño de los elementos flexibles para poder utilizar row warp!!  considerando el tamaño fxLayoutGap para que los items se muestren como queremos **warp permite que los elementos fluyan en varias lineas**
Tambien si dejamos afuera del container a la tabla ocurre que :
Como te comente la vista muestra a select de condicion de venta ocupando un 25 % de la linea o fila y el resto del espacio(75%) lo ocupa el input de nombre de Cliente si la tabla no pertenece al container  y se muestra el resultado en el navegador en la foto .El codigo que copie como respuesta se puede ver tambien en github el cual contiene a  **fxLayout="column  " fxLayout.gt-xs="row warp " fxLayoutGap="20px"**  y la forma de calculo con **calc** ya que muestra como tener control sobre los elementos flexibles
**ruta card**
[codigo github](https://github.com/nestdanchia/NgZone/tree/main/src/app/card)
[image: codigo en github]

[image: Utilizando row warp y cal]

> El codigo muestra  que hay que usar  fxLayout.gt-xs="row warp " para
> un fxLayoutGap="20px"  al agregar un titulo y dos card dentro de
> conteiner sin asi afectar al select y el input los cuales ocupan la
> dimension requerida calculada con calc

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
export interface Cliente {
  name: string;
  precio: number;
  
}
const Client_DATA: Cliente[] = [
  { name: 'Berta', precio: 1.0079},
  { name: 'Omar',precio: 4.0026}
  
];


@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.css']
})

export class CardComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = [ 'name', 'precio'];
  dataSource = Client_DATA;
  myControl = new FormControl();
  myTable = new FormControl();
  options: string[] = ['Berta', 'Omar', 'Ulises'];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

```css
      .container{
        width: 100%;
      }
```

```html
<mat-card class="mat-elevation-z0"> 
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <mat-card-title>Con Nueva Venta Tabla fuera de Container usando row warp y calc</mat-card-title>
</div>
<mat-card-content> 
<form>
<div class="container" fxLayout="column  " fxLayout.gt-xs="row warp " fxLayoutGap="20px"  >
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Condicion de Venta</ng-template>

    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" fxFlex="calc(25%-20px)">
      <mat-label>Condicion.:</mat-label>
      <mat-select placeholder="Condicion de Venta"  cdkFocusInitial>
        <mat-option value=undefined>Seleccione</mat-option>
        <mat-option value=1>Contado</mat-option>
        <mat-option value=2>Cuenta Corriente</mat-option>
      </mat-select>

    </mat-form-field>
 

    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" fxFlex="calc(75%-20px)" >
      <input type="text"
           placeholder="Pick one"
           aria-label="Number"
           matInput
           [formControl]="myControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
  <div fxFlex="calc(100%-20px)">Utilizando row warp y calc se agregan dos Card </div>
  <mat-card class="child-1" fxFlex="calc(25%-20px)">1. One</mat-card> 
  <mat-card class="child-2" fxFlex="calc(75%-20px)">1. Two</mat-card> 
</div>

<br>



<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z1" >
  <caption style="font-size: 20px;height: 4vh;border: 10px; color: rgb(54, 11, 211);"> DETALLE </caption>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="precio">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Precio. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.precio}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>


</form>
</mat-card-content> 

</mat-card>
```

Asi agregamos elementos al conteiner ya que debemos  considerar el tamaño de fxLayoutGap

> para que los elementos se alinien de acuerdo a como querramos con calc mientras warp permite que los elementos fluyan en varias lineas*

**Por ultimo  tabla dentro del conteiner:**

```html
<mat-card class="mat-elevation-z0"> 
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <mat-card-title>Con Nueva Venta Tabla Dentro del Container usando row warp y calc</mat-card-title>
</div>
<mat-card-content> 
<form>
<div class="container" fxLayout="column  " fxLayout.gt-xs="row warp " fxLayoutGap="20px"  >
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Condicion de Venta</ng-template>

    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" fxFlex="calc(25%-20px)">
      <mat-label>Condicion.:</mat-label>
      <mat-select placeholder="Condicion de Venta"  cdkFocusInitial>
        <mat-option value=undefined>Seleccione</mat-option>
        <mat-option value=1>Contado</mat-option>
        <mat-option value=2>Cuenta Corriente</mat-option>
      </mat-select>

    </mat-form-field>
 

    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" fxFlex="calc(75%-20px)" >
      <input type="text"
           placeholder="Pick one"
           aria-label="Number"
           matInput
           [formControl]="myControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
  <div fxFlex="calc(100%-20px)">Utilizando row warp y calc se agregan dos Card </div>
  <mat-card class="child-1" fxFlex="calc(25%-20px)">1. One</mat-card> 
  <mat-card class="child-2" fxFlex="calc(75%-20px)">1. Two</mat-card> 


<div fxFlex="calc(50%-20px)">
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z1" >
  <caption style="font-size: 20px;height: 4vh;border: 10px; color: rgb(54, 11, 211);"> DETALLE </caption>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="precio">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Precio. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.precio}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
</div>


</div>


</form>
</mat-card-content> 

</mat-card>
```

se muestar en el navegador -->
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]